# Force Edit Text to request focus programmatically

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I want to show a custom keypad layout if EditText has focus and after filling the data on button click hide the keypad layout. I'm using FocusChangeListener for this, but once the focus is lost, unable to recreate it.Is there any other way to attain this? My code for button event and editText focus change listener is as follows:

//Handling Focus change listener for edit Text

```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    linearKeypadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    linearKeypadLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
               }
            });
```

//Button click event

```
btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setFocusable(false);
            editText.setText(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you want to keep focus on the edittext  all the times???

Comment: whe you click on the button automatically focus is moved from edittext,Just you use keypad hide code in button click listener.Don't use  editText.setFocusable(false);

Comment: @Sino Yes, just hide the keypad layout after button click

Comment: so do it on button click..why do u want to do it in onFocusChanged?

Comment: But i need to recreate the editText focus after the button click event.Whenever user focus on editText enable the keypad layout

Comment: use editText .requestFocus()